# Display and render only a specific object in wireframe in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I want to know how to view and render a specific game object (mesh) in wireframe, not the whole scene. I can change the scene to wireframe using `GL.wireframe` but the problem I want to view and render only a certain object (not the whole scene) in wireframe. Any advice please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use *Layers*. Change the layer of the game object (dropdown in the top right of the Inspector window) from *Default* to another layer (you can create a new one choosing *Add Layer...* in the dropdown menu).

Then, create a new camera (or select the main camera, depending on what you want to achieve), and change its *Culling Mask* to the layer you are using in the game object.

For drawing the wireframe, you post this script in the camera that's supposed to draw that game object:

```
// from http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL-wireframe.html
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void OnPreRender() {
        GL.wireframe = true;
    }
    void OnPostRender() {
        GL.wireframe = false;
    }
}
```

You may have to use 2 cameras depending on what you want to achieve (one camera for the wireframe object, another camera to draw the rest of the scene), in this case you would set the *Clear Flags* of one of the cameras to *Don't Clear*. Make sure the *Depth* value of both cameras is the same.

The *Clear Flags* of a camera indicates what's going to happen with the pixels where there's nothing to be drawn (the empty space) of that camera, and also what happens when there are multiple cameras drawing to the same pixel.

In the case where *Clear Flags* is *Don't Clear*, it will not do anything with the empty space, leaving it for the other camera to fill with an object or a background. For the pixels where it should draw something, it will let the depth of the object decide what is going to be drawn, that is, the objects that are nearer the camera will be drawn on the top of the others.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already did that but this change the whole scene to wireframe, I only want a certain object or mesh.

Comment: I don't mind having two cameras. And I did exactly what you said but the camera who is responsible for drawing the scene is the only one that renders, the camera which is responsible for the wireframe object doesn't display the object. Any thoughts please? I will upvote your answer anyway for your kind assistance.

Comment: and both cameras are on the same position by the way. But `camera2` is set to view a certain object and `camera1`  is set to view the rest of the scene. But when rendering only the rest of the scene appears using `camera1`.

Comment: _[Note that some platforms, for example mobile (OpenGL ES) does not support wireframe rendering](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL-wireframe.html)_

Comment: @shepherd Did you see my comment?

Answer (score 1):

There is an [asset](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21897) on the **Unity asset store** containing several shader materials which do exactly what you need. You can download it, analyze and write the shaders yourself, or simply use the asset provided.

You can then attach the **shader** to a **material** and that to a **mesh renderer** to attain the desired effect.

Comment: That is no longer true. **Unity 5 free** supports **shaders**. I tested this myself. And even if so, you still can analyse the shaders :). Anyway, this is the solution in case of `gl.wireframe` not being supported.